# 2nd HDD visible on explorer but not in MEGASync app

Tags: hard-drive, mega

i just installed MEGASync .deb package on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to add a folder in my 2nd HDD as my local sync location but the 2nd HDD is not appearing at all in MEGASync's local folder selection window ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ8in.png)). However, the HDD is clearly detected by the OS and i can access it from the explorer ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzwDi.png)).

Any ideas?

Comment: The drive might be detected, but is it mounted? While mounted, browse to the mount-point (probably somewhere in `/media/<user>`) in  MEGASync's local folder selection window.

Comment: @mook765 That's it. Sorry I hadn't understood the concept of linux filesystems. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome, it was just an idea, the good point is that it helped you.